# weight of a rotating mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Imagine a ball attached to one end of a piece of rope and you are holding the other end with your hand. In a static situation in which a you do not whirl the tethered ball, ball's weight is applied to your hand. What if you whirl it so fast that the ball fly to the height of your hand? Does ball's weight still apply to your hand?

Comment: You don't feel a particular force, but rather the *sum* of forces and moving inertia. In static cases that sum just happens (sometimes) to be the weight. In general at any moment, Newton's second law will tell you how much your hand must hold back against: $\sum F=ma$.

Comment: Have you drawn a free body diagram, or do you feel that you have advanced beyond the point where you need to use free body diagrams?

Comment: your right Chester. free body always helps. my following answer is according to a free body. thank you.

Comment: ""What if you whirl it so fast that the ball fly to the height of your hand?"" This is the wrong thinking in your question. "fly to the height of your hand" is simply impossible. The ball will always be a little bit lower than your hand.

Answer (score 1):

Lets us assume that whirl means that the ball under goes [circular motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion), then it is not weight that you will feel on your hand but rather the tension which would be equal to the centripetal force required to keep the ball in a circular motion. Now if you were to jerk the ball upwards and the rope becomes slack then you would feel no force in your hand, until the ball comes down and the rope becomes taut again.

Comment: Hi dear play. but the system must be dynamically equivalent. so  there should be a force equal in size and opposite in direction with the ball's weight.

Comment: Again assuming circular motion there will always have to be a force directed towards the centre to maintain circular motion and this will be what will be felt at the hand. I am not exactly sure what is meant by dynamically equivalent...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the ball is not moving vertically then the net vertical force on it is zero. The downward weight of the ball is balanced by the upward vertical component of the tension in the string. You are holding the string so the weight of the ball is transmitted to your hand via the tension in the string. This  tension is greater than the weight of the ball.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I could find an answer for it. By the way your hand must withstand rope's tension. In static situation T=mg, but when you whirl the rope T = Tsin(θ)i + Tcos(θ)j. Where Tcos(θ)= mg and Tsin(θ)= centripetal force. according to newton's second law, always there should be a force that is equal in size and opposite in direction with ball's weight and we know that Tcos(θ)= mg , thus (θ) can never be 90 degrees.

[image]